# Notification large icon looking small

Tags: java, android, canvas, push-notification

I'm trying to set a drawable in a notification's large icon, but a strange behaviour is happening, the drawable gets smaller for some reason, it's the first notification in this image:

[image]

This is the drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/subject7"/>
        <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        <padding
            android:bottom="7dp"
            android:left="7dp"
            android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_clock_colored_clicked" />
```

This is how I'm setting the largeIcon:

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
notification.setLargeIcon(drawableToBitmap(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), drawableID, null)));

...

public Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Has this happened to anyone?

**Edit:** This is in a BroadcastReceiver, calling itself every 60 seconds to refresh the notification, the first time the largeIcon appears properly, it only appears smaller after the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles into this.

Make the bitmap with an actual PNG, with the proper padding into it, like this:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int color) {
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.notification_class_icon, null);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

    //set round background on lolipop+ and square before
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color));
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, p);
    }
    else {
        canvas.drawColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color));
    }
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

This is R.drawable.notification_class_icon looks:

[image] 
(the black is suposed to be transparent).

Make sure you make one for every dimension.

Then just set the notifications' icon like this and pass the color for the background:

```
notification.setLargeIcon(getBitmap(R.color.colorPrimary));
```